# PHP extract a date from HTML code how to?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

Hi i need some help in extracting a date from the html code below, (below is just snapshot of the what i want to extract, its a full html page)

```
.... <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="color:#ccc;"> </span>&nbsp;
<span style="font-family:'Open Sans', arial;font-size:11px!important;color:#ccc;">0</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" style="color:#ccc;"></span>&nbsp;
<span style="font-family:'Open Sans',arial;font-size:11px!important;color:#ccc;">December 6, 2014</span>
<span style="font-family:'Open Sans',arial;font-size:11px!important;color:#ccc;">2:00 am</span>
<span style="font-family:'Open Sans',arial;font-size:11px!important;color:#ccc;">Hits(6)</span>....
```

So i tried to use the following code using PHP DOM object and the XPATH to do a find, but failed with result length is zero. Why ?

```
//libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom_document = new DOMDocument(); // CREATE A NEW DOCUMENT
        $dom_document->loadHTML(
            mb_convert_encoding($row['html'], 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')
        ); // LOAD THE STRING INTO THE DOCUMENT
        $classname = "font-family:'Open Sans',arial;font-size:11px!important;color:#ccc;";
        $xpath     = new DOMXPath($dom_document);
        $results   = $xpath->query("//*[@span=\"" . $classname . "\"]");
            var_dump($results);
        if ($results->length > 0) {
            $date = $results->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
        //libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$classname` is misleading/confusing, it doesn't contain a class name which is inside your sample markup but a **css style rules**.

```
$classname = "font-family:'Open Sans',arial;font-size:11px!important;color:#ccc;";
```

You should be searching nodes which has a style of that rule:

```
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@style=\"" . $classname . "\"]");
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/N7GOQg)